# How do I uninstall an ActiveX control via Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, windows-installer, activex

I have to constantly switch back and forth between two installations of a web app with two different versions of an ActiveX control. Therefore I'd like to script the ability to uninstall this control. Its does not show up in [Win32_Product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(v=vs.85).aspx) because it was not installed via windows installer, and contrary to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797435/how-to-enumerate-all-activex-elements-with-wmi/801929#801929), the [Win32_ClassicCOMClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394086(v=vs.85).aspx) does not contain this ActiveX control.

[AXHelper](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/axhelper.html) shows the control in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID. So my two questions are:

- How do I enumerate the control with WMI
- How do I uninstall the control with WMI

Answer (score 2):

You can usually find the activex ocx file in C:\windows\Downloaded Program Files.

To uninstall use cmd in powershell as `cmd /c 'regsvr32 /u "C:\windows\Downloaded Program Files\youractivex.ocx"`

Use `$lastexitcode` to verify success

Once it's uninstalled remove the ocx file from the downloaded program files folder and copy in the ocx file for the different version then install just as the uninstall command but without the /u

Comment: James, the program is not stored there, but I know where it is. I will try this later today.

Comment: That uninstalls the OCX, but does not remove it from the Programs and Features (Add Remove Programs on XP and previous).